# How to properly declare, change and use workflow process variables?

Tags: javascript, workflow, alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

Based on the [example](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) kindly provided by Mr. Potts, I've developed the system of the contracts approval.

Business process in BPMN notation is presented below.

By [Activiti Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer](https://www.activiti.org/designer/update):

[image]

The scheme of a running business process in Alfresco:

[image]

For creating activiti diagrams I used Activiti Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer 5.18. Here is a description of the process that was generated by this plug-in:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="contractsApproval" name="Contracts Approval" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start" activiti:formKey="scwf:submitReviewTask"></startEvent>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="Approval of the first group" activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_First" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiFirstReview">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {
                            var newApprovedCount = scwf_approveCount + 1;
                            execution.setVariable('scwf_approveCount', newApprovedCount);
                        }]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="usertask3" name="Revise" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiRevise">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_reviseOutcome') == 'Re-submit') {
                    execution.setVariable('scwf_resubmit', true);
                    } else {
                    execution.setVariable('scwf_resubmit', false);
                    }]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="usertask4" name="Approval of the second group" activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_Second" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiSecondReview">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {
                            var newApprovedCount = scwf_approveCount + 1;
                            execution.setVariable('scwf_approveCount', newApprovedCount);
                        }
        ]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <serviceTask id="scripttask1" name="Send a document for approval" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:field name="runAs">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[admin]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
        <activiti:field name="script">
          <activiti:string><![CDATA[execution.setVariable('scwf_approveCount', 0);
            execution.setVariable('scwf_tpApproved', false);]]></activiti:string>
        </activiti:field>
      </extensionElements>
    </serviceTask>
    <parallelGateway id="parallelgateway1" name="Parallel Gateway"></parallelGateway>
    <parallelGateway id="parallelgateway2" name="Parallel Gateway"></parallelGateway>
    <exclusiveGateway id="exclusivegateway1" name="Exclusive Gateway"></exclusiveGateway>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="scripttask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="scripttask1" targetRef="parallelgateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow4" sourceRef="parallelgateway1" targetRef="usertask4"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow5" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="parallelgateway2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow6" sourceRef="usertask4" targetRef="parallelgateway2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow7" sourceRef="parallelgateway2" targetRef="exclusivegateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow9" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="usertask3">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${scwf_approveCount < 2}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow13" sourceRef="usertask3" targetRef="scripttask1">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${scwf_resubmit == true}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="usertask5" name="Approved Notification" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="scwf:activitiApprovedNotification">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[var setWebFlagAction = actions.create("set-web-flag");
                        setWebFlagAction.parameters["active"] = true;
                        for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++) {
                            logger.log("Approving node:" + bpm_package.children[i].nodeRef);
                            setWebFlagAction.execute(bpm_package.children[i]);
                        }]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow15" sourceRef="usertask5" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow16" sourceRef="usertask3" targetRef="endevent1">
      <conditionExpression xsi:type="tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${scwf_resubmit == false}]]></conditionExpression>
    </sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow17" sourceRef="exclusivegateway1" targetRef="usertask5"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_contractsApproval">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="contractsApproval" id="BPMNPlane_contractsApproval">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="0.0" y="163.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent1" id="BPMNShape_endevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="790.0" y="164.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="usertask1" id="BPMNShape_usertask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="75.0" width="105.0" x="330.0" y="96.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="usertask3" id="BPMNShape_usertask3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="310.0" y="360.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="usertask4" id="BPMNShape_usertask4">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="78.0" width="105.0" x="330.0" y="193.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="scripttask1" id="BPMNShape_scripttask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="89.0" width="121.0" x="60.0" y="136.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="parallelgateway1" id="BPMNShape_parallelgateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="230.0" y="162.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="parallelgateway2" id="BPMNShape_parallelgateway2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="480.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusivegateway1" id="BPMNShape_exclusivegateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="568.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="usertask5" id="BPMNShape_usertask5">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="68.0" width="105.0" x="640.0" y="147.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="35.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="60.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="181.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="230.0" y="182.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow3" id="BPMNEdge_flow3">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="250.0" y="162.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="250.0" y="137.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="330.0" y="133.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow4" id="BPMNEdge_flow4">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="250.0" y="202.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="250.0" y="233.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="330.0" y="232.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow5" id="BPMNEdge_flow5">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="435.0" y="133.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="500.0" y="137.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="500.0" y="160.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow6" id="BPMNEdge_flow6">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="435.0" y="232.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="500.0" y="233.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="500.0" y="200.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow7" id="BPMNEdge_flow7">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="520.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="568.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow9" id="BPMNEdge_flow9">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="588.0" y="200.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="362.0" y="360.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow13" id="BPMNEdge_flow13">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="362.0" y="360.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="120.0" y="225.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow15" id="BPMNEdge_flow15">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="745.0" y="181.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="790.0" y="181.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow16" id="BPMNEdge_flow16">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="415.0" y="387.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="598.0" y="387.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="807.0" y="199.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow17" id="BPMNEdge_flow17">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="608.0" y="180.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="640.0" y="181.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Here is the workflow content model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Definition of new Model -->
<model name="scwf:workflowModel"
       xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

    <!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
    <description>...</description>
    <author>...</author>
    <version>...</version>

    <!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
    <imports>
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0" prefix="bpm" />
    </imports>

    <!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
    <namespaces>
        <namespace uri="http://.../model/workflow/1.0" prefix="scwf" />
    </namespaces>

    <types>

        <type name="scwf:submitReviewTask">
            <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        </type>

        <type name="scwf:activitiFirstReview">
            <parent>scwf:activitiReviewTask</parent>
        </type>

        <type name="scwf:activitiSecondReview">
            <parent>scwf:activitiReviewTask</parent>
        </type>

        <type name="scwf:activitiRevise">
            <parent>bpm:activitiOutcomeTask</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="scwf:reviseOutcome">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <default>Abort</default>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint type="LIST">
                            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                                <list>
                                    <value>Re-submit</value>
                                    <value>Abort</value>
                                </list>
                            </parameter>
                        </constraint>
                    </constraints>
                </property>
            </properties>               
            <overrides>
                <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                    <default>edit_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
                <property name="bpm:outcomePropertyName">
                    <default>{http://.../model/workflow/1.0}reviseOutcome</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>
        </type>

        <type name="scwf:activitiReviewTask">
            <parent>bpm:activitiOutcomeTask</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="scwf:approveRejectOutcome">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <default>Reject</default>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint type="LIST">
                            <parameter name="allowedValues">
                                <list>
                                    <value>Approve</value>
                                    <value>Reject</value>
                                </list>
                            </parameter>
                        </constraint>
                    </constraints>
                </property>
            </properties>               
            <overrides>
                <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                    <default>read_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
                <property name="bpm:outcomePropertyName">
                    <default>{http://.../model/workflow/1.0}approveRejectOutcome</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>
        </type>

        <type name="scwf:activitiApprovedNotification">
            <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
            <overrides>
                <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                    <default>read_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>            
        </type>
    </types>
</model>
```

On my local computer installed:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.d (r134641-b15, Aikau 1.0.101.3, Spring Surf
>   5.2.d, Spring WebScripts 6.13, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r134428-b13) schema 10005

And everything works fine...

However, the problem occurs when I installed the system on the server, where:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.c (r133673-b12, Aikau 1.0.99, Spring Surf 5.2.c,
>   Spring WebScripts 6.11, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino
>   1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r133656-b12) schema 10005

In the process of approval, I get this error message:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in
>   expression: ${scwf_approveCount < 2}

**NB**: Error appears only after processing by the next group (no matter first or second) - for example, if the contract approved / rejected by the first group, then the second group can't neither approve nor reject.

The portal [ecmarchitect](http://ecmarchitect.com) says that:

*"You may be wondering why this is a service task instead of a script task. In 5.0.d, the underlying JavaScript engine in Activiti switched from Rhino to Nashorn. This caused a problem related to setting execution variables. The work around is to use a service task."*

And shows the example of how to initialize variables:

```
<serviceTask id="scripttask1" name="Submit" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="script">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[execution.setVariable('scwf_approveCount', 0);
          execution.setVariable('scwf_tpApproved', false);]]></activiti:string>
    </activiti:field>
  </extensionElements>
</serviceTask>
```

I found several discussions about this, but none of the approach described in them did not help in my case:

- [Unknown property used in expression](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/208871-unknown-property-used-in-expression)
- [ExceptionActiviti: unknown property used in expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498269/exceptionactiviti-unknown-property-used-in-expression)
- [Advanced Workflow Tutorials](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/176855-advanced-workflow-tutorials)
- [Property Not Defined](https://community.alfresco.com/message/683851-re-property-not-defined?commentID=683851#comment-683851)
- [Property error on JavaScript variables](https://community.alfresco.com/message/590485-property-error-on-javascript-variables)

For example, I tried to initialize the variables by these ways:

```
...

<scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Submit" scriptFormat="javascript" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
    <script>var scwf_approveCount = 0; var scwf_tpApproved = false;</script>
</scriptTask>

...

<scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Submit" scriptFormat="javascript">
<script><![CDATA[var scwf_approveCount = 0; var scwf_tpApproved =
false;]]></script>
</scriptTask>

...

<scriptTask id="scripttask1" name="Submit" scriptFormat="javascript" activiti:autoStoreVariables="true">
    <script>execution.setVariable('scwf_approveCount', 0); execution.setVariable('scwf_tpApproved', false);</script>
</scriptTask>

...
```

I think that I need to reinstall Alfresco on the server for matching the local installation.

Is there another way to solve this problem? I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

---

Additional information: I installed exactly the same systems. On the server and on my local computer:

> Alfresco Share v5.2.d (r134641-b15, Aikau 1.0.101.3, Spring Surf
>   5.2.d, Spring WebScripts 6.13, Freemarker 2.3.20-alfresco-patched, Rhino 1.7R4-alfresco-patched, Yui 2.9.0-alfresco-20141223)
>
> Alfresco Community v5.2.0 (r134428-b13) schema 10005

But it's very strange - locally everything works fine but on the server I get the same error again:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Unknown property used in
>   expression: ${scwf_approveCount < 2}

I compared the data in the diagram and in the underlying XML and they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scwf_approveCount You are using this property make sure that you have defined this property in your workflow's model file as scwf: approveCount 
You are using this property scwf_approveCount and it may be not defined in your model file.

Comment: yes you are right. but if you declare the variable as scwf_approveCount it means you are using the property of your content model scwf:approveCount so if you wanted to declare variable you can simply use approveCount as variable